# Aptana 3, App Explorer: Add new view filters?

Tags: filter, aptana, aptana3

In Aptana 3, you can set what filters you want for the App Explorer view by click the arrow in the top right of the view and selecting "Customize View...". My question is, does anyone know of a way to create custom filters? Specifically, I want to see certain hidden files like .htaccess, but want to hide others like .svn directories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click at App Explorer at any folder (for me its currently for example root folder -> app). Then go **Properties** -> **Resource** -> **Resource Filters** and then to the left **Add**, you can specify any filter that match string u like include or exclude it from the view or specify diffrent attributes You like. 
I hope that helps ;)